# Is it possible to get a different header.php on language switch with qtranslate (Wordpress)?

Tags: qtranslate

the problem is that on home page I have a lot of code which is added through header.php and it is not amendable through admin panel. What I want to do is to switch header files on language switch. Whenever a user press on the language icon, lets say on the English language icon the header should also switch from `<?php get_header('mylanguage') ?>` to `<?php get_header('english') ?>` or etc. Is it possible to do like this?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

In your page template instead of calling header through:

```
get_header();
```

use this to enable header switching when changing languages;

```
<?php if (qtrans_getLanguage() == 'de'): ?>
    <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/header-home-de.php' ); ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/header-home-en.php' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In this example there are 2 headers depending on selected language.

Answer (score 0):

Surely, it is possible in qTranslate. Even I've done qTranslate Swicher in bootstrap navigation.

```
<?php } if (qtranxf_getLanguage() == 'en') { ?>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">English</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <?php echo qtranxf_generateLanguageSelectCode('code'); ?>
    </ul>
<?php } elseif (qtranxf_getLanguage() == 'fr') { ?>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Français</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <?php echo qtranxf_generateLanguageSelectCode('code'); ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```